# Интеграция формы обратной связи и Trello

Tags: php, trello

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно интегрировать форму обратной связи на сайте и Trello так, чтобы запросы, которые приходят на сайт, автоматически появлялись в Trello в виде отдельных задач? Имею в виду укрупненно основные этапы алгоритма.

Answer (score 1):

```
// This code sample uses the 'Unirest' library:
// http://unirest.io/php.html
$query = array(
  'key' => '0471642aefef5fa1fa76530ce1ba4c85',
  'token' => '9eb76d9a9d02b8dd40c2f3e5df18556c831d4d1fadbe2c45f8310e6c93b5c548',
  'idList' => '5abbe4b7ddc1b351ef961414'
);

$response = Unirest\Request::post(
  'https://api.trello.com/1/cards',
  $query
);

var_dump($response)
```

https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/rest/api-group-cards/#api-cards-post